# Watir - Chrome - How to retrieve all "li" entries that are not all visible?

Tags: google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm working on test automation of a Chrome based chatting/IM platform.

One of the case is to get all contacts info. Contacts are placed in groups and can be seen or hidden by by toggle-clicking group name.

I was trying to post an image but got rejected saying I don't have enough reputation points :(

The HTML source is like the following:

---

```
    <div id="connectionListItems">
      <ul class="connections" style="height: 2783px;">
        <li class="group collapsed" data-item-id="SUGAR" data-name="SUGAR" style="top: 0px;"> ... /li>
        <li class="group collapsed" data-item-id="Desk Connections" data-name="Desk Connections" style="top: 23px;"> ... /li>
        <li class="group expanded" data-item-id="Default" data-name="Default" style="top: 46px;">
          <span class="name"> Default <span class="count">(0/118)</span> </span>  ... /li>
        <li class="connection" data-item-id="Default~klxkqbs_tu-yahoo" style="top: 69px;">
          <span class="name">(ABN) James</span>  </li>
        <li class="connection" data-item-id="Default~klxkqbs_tq-yahoo" style="top: 92px;">
          <span class="name">(ABN) Justin</span> </li>
        <li class="connection" data-item-id="Default~klxkqbs_wm-yahoo" style="top: 115px;">
          <span class="name">(ABN) Matt</span>  </li>
       .......
     </ul>
   </div>
```

---

My Watir script is like the following:

---

```
    def getContactCount(browser, outputfile)
      iframe_chat = browser.iframe(:src => "/tribe/connectionlist/index.html#appId/3")
      ul_conns = iframe_chat.div(:id => "connectionList").div(:id => "connectionListItems").ul(:class => "connections")
      numGroups = ul_conns.lis(:class => /group/).length
      outputfile.puts "- Contact count -- total groups: " + numGroups.to_s
      grpName = Array.new
      ul_conns.lis(:class => /group/).each { |li| grpName.push li.data_name }
      for igrp in 1..numGroups
         list_grp = ul_conns.li(:data_name => grpName[igrp-1])
         outputfile.puts "     Group " + list_grp.text
         list_grp.click
         outputfile.puts "     Number of contacts found: " + ul_conns.lis(:class => "connection").length.to_s
         ul_conns.lis(:class => "connection").each { |li| outputfile.puts "        " + li.span(:class => "name").text }
         list_grp.click
      end
    end
```

---

And this is the output:

---

```
    - Contact count -- total groups: 3
     Group SUGAR (0/11)
     Number of contacts found: 11
        (GFI) Joachim
        (ICAP) Kissel
        (JB Drax) James
        (JB Drax) Simon
        (JPM) Jason
        (JPM) Jeb
        (JSG) Steven
        (Macq) NY SB Desk
        (NE) Chris
        (RJO) Babe
        (RJO) Croce
     Group Desk Connections (1/88)
     Number of contacts found: 55
        ICM_am
        (ABN) Alex
        (ABN) James
        (ABN) Justin
        (ADM) Marie
        (Alliance) Victor
        (Arfinco) Bruno
        (Arfinco) Nico
        .......
     Group Default (0/118)
     Number of contacts found: 54
        (ABN) James
        (ABN) Justin
        (ABN) Matt
        ......
```

---

The problem is, for group "Desk Connections" and "Default", only part of the contacts were retrieved by the script (55 of 88, 54 of 118, repectively).

Actually, when I was checking the HTML source in the Chrome browser, only part of them were listed too. But when I scrolled the frame down, more were shown (but the ones on top became invisible).

Could anyone take a look and help? How do I get all the "li"s (class="connection")?

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's sounding like the page HTML/DOM gets updated when you scroll the frame down, so all the lis that you want don't exist when you reference them.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: How is the frame scrolled? Is it just a regular scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, just a regular scroll bar (vertical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key to solving your problem is scrolling the frame. You can scroll to the end (ie last element) of the frame using:

```
browser.frame(:id => 'frame_id).elements.last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

In theory, once you do this, it will cause the next set of elements to load (and the others to disappear).

Since you can only see (in the DOM) one page of results at a time, you will need to capture results, scroll to the bottom, wait for the list to reload and then capture more results.

This is roughly what you need to do (though I am guessing without a test page):

```
# Get the results of your first 'page'
results = iframe_chat.lis.collect(&:text)

# Scroll to the bottom to get more results
iframe_chat.elements.last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view

# Wait for the list to refresh 
# I am checking that the last li disappears.
# You may need to check for something to appear as well.
iframe_chat.li(:text => results.last).wait_while_present

# Get the results of your second 'page'
results = iframe_chat.lis.collect(&:text)
```

Comment: This works:
`for igrp in 1..numGroups`

`  ul_conns.lis(:class => "connection").last.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view`


Thanks a lot, Justin.